# Is there any way to kill a companion permanently in the standard game modes?

Tags: fallout-4

Like the title states, is there any way to kill a companion? I ask this because certain companions are a nuisance.

Comment: What prevents you from simply sending them to a settlement you never visit?

Answer (score 3):

Sort of. There are only three companions you can kill normally: Deacon, Danse, and X6-88.

The way to kill Danse is by following any storyline except for the Minutemen storyline. This will eventually lead to the quest [Blind Betrayal](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Blind_Betrayal), which gives you the opportunity to kill him.

To kill Deacon, you need to follow either the BOS story or the Institute story. This will lead to either [Tactical Thinking](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Tactical_Thinking) or [The End of the Line](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/End_of_the_Line).

You can kill X6-88 by following any main storyline except that of the Insitute to completion.

For any other companion you wish to kill, you need to use console commands.

Comment: Appreciate it, typing on a phone can make it difficult to format and spell correctly